# Is there a $5 \times 5$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that its characteristic polynomial is not solvable by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Can we find a matrix of order 5   in the field of rational numbers such that its characteristic polynomial is not solvable by radicals ?

From Galois Theory we know that every polynomial of degree less than five with  rational number coefficients is solvable by radicals. 
But, $x^5-x+1$ is a polynomial of degree five that is not solvable by radicals.
For example, can we find a $5 \times 5$  matrix  with entries in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that its characteristic polynomial is $x^5-x+1$?

Comment: Every companion matrix of a polynomial has that polynomial as its charpoly.

Comment: Hello, I read your comment, my problem is solved by your comment,

Comment: I sincerely thank you for your cooperation